# Нужен алгоритм, который понимает, что знак меняется python

Tags: python

Я новичек в python и нужно узнать сколько раз в последовательности чисел меняется знак

```
import math
s = " "
Kol = 0
print ('Введите количество чисел')
n = int(input())
print('Введите первое число последовательности')
k = float(input())
for i in range(n-1):
    print('Введите число последовательности')
    z = float(input())
    if (ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ УСЛОВИЕ, которое понимает что знак сменился):
        Kol = Kol + 1
        print('знак поменялся')
if Kol > 0:
    print('\nЗнак поменялся ', "%5.2f" %(Kol), 'раз')
else:
    print('Знак не менялся');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смена знаков определяется логическим выражением `(a<0)^(b<0)`.

```
from functools import reduce

n = 0
def change(a,b):
    global n
    if (a<0)^(b<0): n+=1
    return b

reduce(change,arr)
arr = [1,-5,5,4,-8]
assert n == 3
```

reduce попарно применяет функцию к прошлому результату и следующему элементу, это можно переписать на for или while

`nonlocal b` - если n объявленно в функции

Comment: Проще так: a*b < 0

Comment: а по мне логикой и быстрее и нагляднее

Answer (score 7):

Если однострочник

```
sum(a*b < 0 for a,b in zip(data[1:],data[:-1]))
```

Comment: идея хорошая, в списке не только же 1 и -1?

Comment: не очень понял, вроде все ответы не рассчитаны на +-1

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, перемножение двух чисел с одинаковым знаком дает положительное число, перемножение двух чисел с разным знаком - отрицательное. Если после умножения двух соседних чисел получилось отрицательное число, значит знак поменялся.

Answer (score 3):

Ну и для любителей однострочников:

```
from itertools import groupby


data = [-1, 5, 6, 7, -2, -4, -6, 1, 2, 3]

groups = len(list(groupby(data, key=lambda x: -1 if x <0 else 1)))

print('Знак сменился {} раз'.format(groups-1))
```